# Detecting 302 Redirect

Tags: c#, url, redirect, response.redirect

I'm trying to check the redirect location of a url but am always getting the wrong results. For example, for the url http://www.yellowpages.com.eg/Mjg3NF9VUkxfMTEwX2h0dHA6Ly93d3cubG90dXMtYWlyLmNvbV8=/Lotus-Air/profile.html, it redirects to http://www.lotus-air.com with a type of redirect 302 Found (you can test it on the this service http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/), however am getting "http://mobile.yellowpages.com.eg/" as the webResp.GetResponseHeader("Location") . My Code is as follows:

```
        string url = @"http://www.yellowpages.com.eg/Mjg3NF9VUkxfMTEwX2h0dHA6Ly93d3cubG90dXMtYWlyLmNvbV8=/Lotus-Air/profile.html";


        HttpWebRequest webReq = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        webReq.Method = "HEAD";
        webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        HttpWebResponse webResp = webReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        txtOutput.Text += webResp.StatusCode.ToString() + "\r\n" ;
        txtOutput.Text += webResp.GetResponseHeader("Location") + "\r\n";
        txtOutput.Text += webResp.ResponseUri.ToString();

        webResp.Close();
```

Thanks.

Yehia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben pointed out, it redirects based on user agent. Just add some user agent (this one is for chrome):

```
webReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13";
```

For me it redirects to http://www.lotus-air.com.

Answer (score 3):

They are probably sending different redirects based on the user agent, so you get one result in a browser and another in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use  a HTTP debugging proxy to get an understanding of the headers moving back and forth and enables to you to change your user-agent to help test Ben's theory (I +1'd that).

A good one is [Fiddler - Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) free and easy to use/

The screenshot below shows me changing the useragent to an old IEMobile one "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows CE; IEMobile 6.12; en-US; KIN.Two 1.0)", which redirects me to mobile.yellowpages.com.eg

n.b. changing to an ipad useragent takes you to iphone.yellowpages.com.eg

[image: Switching the user agent to one of a mobile phone, redirects you to mobile.yellowpages.com.eg]

Comment: +1 I agree fiddler is a fantastic tool for this kind of debugging

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I totally agree. The ol'fiddler an essential tool, I think I must use it everyday. Just got me thinking, to show my support I just +1'd the fiddler in google! :-)